# How to encode (base64) and decode(base64) more than one variable which is passing via url in php

Tags: php

I want to pass more than one variable via url. I do not want to show those values to the user.Therefore while passing the variable via url I encode the by base64 and in another file I decode it and I will use. I am able to do this for one variable.But, I want to implement the same for more than one variable. I am not getting how to do this.

Can anyone assist me?

My code is,

encode.php

```
<?php
    $link = "decrypt.php?item=".urlencode(base64_encode('testing'))."";
    echo '<a href='.$link.'>click here</a>';
?>
```

decode.php

```
<?php
    foreach($_GET as $loc=>$item)
       $_GET[$loc] = base64_decode(urldecode($item));
       echo $_GET[$loc];
?>
```

But, I should pass more than one like

```
<a href="test.php?name="Suma"&place="India"">click</a>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: "I do not want to show those values to the user." — Then don't pass the data to the browser in the first place. Base64 encoding is a very ineffective means of obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer:)

I have like this,

My code is,

encode.php

```
<?php
    $link = "decrypt.php? 
   item=".urlencode(base64_encode('testing'))."&rate=".urlencode(base64_encode('10'))."";
echo '<a href='.$link.'>click here</a>';
?>
```

decode.php

```
<?php
    echo base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['item']));
    echo base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['rate']));
?>
```

Comment: You do realise that base64 encoded string are quite obviously that and can easily be decoded by a user?